# T(n) = 9T(n/2)+n^3 solving a recurrence equation using master theorem

Tags: algorithm, performance, recurrence

I followed this theorem to solve it:

[image]

My solution to this problem: 9T(n/2)+n^3 was theta(n^log base 2 (9)), is it correct? If not, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Making `n = 2^m` and substituting we have

`T[2^m] = 9 T[2^(m-1)]+2^(3m)`

than can be recast as

`R[m] = 9 R[m-1] + 2^(3m)`

this linear recurrence ca be solved as `R[m] = Rh[m] + Rp[m]` with

`Rh[m] - 9 Rh[m-1] = 0`  and `Rp[m] - 9 Rp[m-1] = 2^(3m)`

and `Rh[m] = c0 9^m`. Now considering `Rp[m] = c0[m]9^m`and substituting int the complete recurrence we obtain

`c0[m]9^m-9c0[m-1]9^(m-1) = 2^(3m)` or

`c0[m] -c0[m-1] = (8/9)^m`

and thus

`c0[m] = ((8/9)^(m+1) - 1)/((8/9) - 1)`  so

`Rp[m] = ((8/9)^(m+1) - 1)/((8/9) - 1)9^m` and thus

`R[m] = (c0 + ((8/9)^(m+1) - 1)/((8/9) - 1)9^m`

and finally the backwards step needed do obtain `T[n]` is left to the reader.